# App name issue with Imported Cordova android app

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am creating android app using Cordova. For that I am using the following commands in cmd.

1. cordova create **example** com.path.example **ExampleApp**
2. cd **example**
3. cordova platform add android
4. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
5. cordova build android

After these process and copying all webpage codings in **assets/www** folder successfully.
After this

- I import it into eclipse the project is created as **MainActivity** not **ExampleApp**. Also I cannot change the App name. I changed app name in **config.xml** and **AndroidManifest.xml** file and tried many things. But no use.

so I created a new project and imported. But I cannot import that app because of the new app also have the **MainActivity** as app name. I googled and searched more over in Stackoverflow and other sites. But cannot fix. Please advise.

Comment: The official SDK for Android and Cordova is Android Studio. Have a look here http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/index.html and here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem by doing following steps,

1. Open AndroidManifest.xml file from
   **platforms->android->AndroidManifest.xml**
2. Change as **android:name="Project_name"** and
   **android:label="@string/app_name"** in **activity**

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="FLP" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>`

3. After that import your project into eclipse.